# C# HttpWebRequest accessing RESTful web service

Tags: c#, ruby, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have a REST web service written in jRuby with entry point http://localhost:4567/v4/start.htm

The web service downloads data from SQL server and sends it to a client.

How do I use C# and httpWebrequest to access the functions provided by the web service.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to use C#? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried httpWebRequest.But I can't get the functions provided by the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you're going to do something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
Request.Method = "GET"; //Or PUT, DELETE, POST
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (HttpWebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
   if (Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
      throw new Exception("The request did not complete successfully and returned status code " + Response.StatusCode);
   using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
      string ReturnedData=Reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

I haven't mixed RoR and C# yet (let alone jRuby), but it should be just a basic modification of the above.